# Simple ReactiveUI object property don't fire

Tags: reactiveui

I am new to ReactiveUI, and I am trying to make a simple reactive object with reactive properties.
I am failing to get the notification when the property is set.
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ReactiveUI;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace SUReactiveUITest
{
    public class MyRepository : ReactiveObject
    {
        Point3D _SyncPoint;
        public Point3D SyncPoint
        {
            get { return _SyncPoint; }
            set
            {
                _SyncPoint = value;
                this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _SyncPoint, value);
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
        }

        MyRepository repo = new MyRepository();
        Program()
        {
            repo.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SyncPoint).Subscribe(OnNewSyncPoint);
            repo.SyncPoint = new Point3D(1, 2, 3);
            repo.SyncPoint = new Point3D(10, 20, 30);
        }

        void OnNewSyncPoint(Point3D p)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("My point NEW value: {0}", p);
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting to that `OnNewSyncPoint()` to be called, and the output should be: 
     My point NEW value: 1,2,3
     My point NEW value: 10,20,30
But nothing is printed :(

Comment: get rid of _SyncPoint = value;  that is setting the value before RaiseAndSetIfChanged does the real work and is thus unchanged or no change in the observed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kenny deserves the real credit. He is correct the RaiseAndSetIfChanged will set the value directly so you don't need the _SyncPoint = value;

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kenny for the answer. Here is the documentation for it:
From [ReactiveUI documentation](http://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/view-models/index.html):
Read-Write Properties

Properties that participate in change notification (i.e. that signal when they are changed), are written in the following way:

```
string name;
public string Name {
    get { return name; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref name, value); }
}
```

Note, that unlike in other frameworks, they are **always written this way**, using the exact same boilerplate code. If you are attempting to put anything in the setter, you are almost certainly Doing It Wrong, and instead should be using WhenAny and ToProperty instead.